# NumPy: Get indices of elements of array after insertion in sorted array

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the code

```
import numpy as np

v = np.linspace(0, 9, 10)
w = np.array([3.5, 4.5])
idx = np.searchsorted(v, w)
v = np.insert(v, idx, w)

print(idx, v[idx])
```

which outputs

```
[4 5] array([3.5, 4. ])
```

The variable `idx` contains the indices of the elements of `w` if they were inserted in `v` one by one. When inserting an array into another like above, only the value of `idx` corresponding to the minimum value of `w` will give as well the position of the same value into `v`.

Is there a way with numpy functions to obtain the indices of the elements of `w` once inserted?

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: An automated way to obtain the indices of the values of ```w``` into ```v```. A variable ```idx_new``` such that ```v[idx_new] == w``` is ```True``` element by element

Comment: Add 1 for each prior index

Comment: @MadPhysicist see the answer of Dani Mesejo below. does not work if ```w``` is not sorted. Answer by Giovanni Tardini works perfect.

Comment: @G.Gare I added a comment on how to fix it

Comment: @G.Gare Doing searchsorted in the array after inserting the elements is worst than sorting the elements beforehand

Comment: No, because v has already w inserted

Comment: so it's ```m log(m)``` or ```m log(m + n)``` additional cost. You're right actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution:

```
import numpy as np

v = np.linspace(0, 9, 10)
w = np.array([3.5, 4.5])
idx = np.searchsorted(v, w)
v = np.insert(v, idx, w)

new_idx = idx + np.arange(len(idx))
print(new_idx, v[new_idx])
```

**Output**

```
[4 5] [3.5 4.5]
```

Comment: doesn't work if ```w``` is not sorted

Comment: @G.Gare Why don't sort `w` then?

Comment: if ```w``` has a million entries you may want to avoid that, but it's a good solution nevertheless!

Comment: You need to apply the argsort of the argsort of the index to the range for a general solution

Comment: @MadPhysicist how?

Comment: @G.Gare `np.arange(len(idx))[idx.argsort().argsort()]`

Comment: @MadPhysicist better than sorting w beforehand?

Comment: @G.Gare. Good call, that would be approximately 2x faster, or better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246875/discussion-between-g-gare-and-mad-physicist).

Comment: This answer is the best if the vector ```w``` is sorted, or with a pre-sorting of ```w```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the most elegant solution is

```
idx_new = idx + np.argsort(np.argsort(idx))
```

but probably not the fastest

Comment: This is the second to most elegant solution :) Most elegant is pre-sorting the data to begin with, since that only requires one sort instead of 2

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, I hope it is general enough

```
import numpy as np
v = np.linspace(0, 9, 10)
w = np.array([3.5, 4.5])
idx = np.searchsorted(v, w)
v = np.insert(v, idx, w)

print(idx, v[idx])
idx_new = np.searchsorted(v, w)
print(idx_new)
print(v[idx_new], w)
```